# C#, При запросе API ничего не возвращает, почему?

Tags: c#, api, get, datetime

Пишу простенькую АПИшку, особо не разбираюсь. Пытаюсь сделать GET запрос из таблицы по промежутку времени, выглядит код метода так:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get sales by dates
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fromDateTime"></param>
/// <param name="toDateTime"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpGet("getbydates")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Sale>> GetByDatesTimeAsync(DateTime fromDateTime, DateTime toDateTime)
{
    var userBook =  _dbContext.Sales.Where(x => x.createdateTime <= fromDateTime && x.createdateTime >= toDateTime);
    if (userBook == null)
        return NotFound();
    return new ObjectResult(userBook);
}
```

Comment: Вы не материализуете запрос

Comment: `IQueryable` работает слегка не так как `IEnumerable`. `IEnumerable` просто применяет ряд функций к копии коллекции. В `IQueryable` же большинство функций просто являються блоками для постороения запроса к базе данных, а этот запрос ещё нужно выполнить. Выполнение запроса вызваеться по разному, вы можете, к примеру, просто дописать `.ToList()` после `Where(...)`